# Tmux: no pane 'zoom' indication after customising status bar

Tags: tmux

My customised `.tmux.conf` file looks like this: [tmux.conf](https://github.com/mikeys/dotfiles/blob/master/tmux.conf)

When I zoom inside a pane in Tmux, I have no 'Z' indication beside the pane title in the status bar. I assume it's because I customised my status bar.

Is there any special 'flag' or character I should use in my .tmux.conf in order to have the 'Z' zoom indicator back?

Thanks

Comment: The flag appears to be "Z" - check this answer for more details: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184255/42887

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to use the window flags option in your customization, which is `#F`.

Note that this is the same flag for indicating that a window is active, etc. I don't know of a way to show the zoom indicator but not show the other general window status indicators.

You can check out the Formats section in the tmux man page for the full list of options.

Comment: Seems that you're right, doesn't seem like it's possible to isolate the zoom indicator. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

From tmux 2.0 onward, you can use the `#{?window_zoomed_flag,ZOOMTEXT,NON-ZOOM TEXT}` replacement conditional in your `window-status-current-format` string.

For example, I use:

```
#{?window_zoomed_flag,#[fg=red](,}#W#{?window_zoomed_flag,#[fg=red]),}
```

To surround the window name with red parenthesis when it is zoomed.

Comment: There is no `window_zoomed_flag` in tmux 1.9a.